How to flatten a tree of table columns into a flat list of table columns with headers
I have a nested tree of table columns. Here are the typescript types.
export interface TableLeafColumn {
  label: string;
  key?: string;
}

export interface TableContainerColumn {
  label: string;
  columns: TableColumn[];
}

// Union type to represent either a leaf or container column
export type TableColumn = TableLeafColumn<T> | TableContainerColumn;

Here's an example of such a type:
const columns: TableColumn[] = [
  {
    label: "Name",
    key: "name",
  },
  {
    label: "Details",
    columns: [
      {
        label: "Age",
        key: "age",
      },
      {
        label: "Address",
        columns: [
          { label: "City", key: "city" },
          { label: "Country", key: "country" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

I would like a function called flattenColumns that will return TableColumn[][]. For example, the input above would return:
const result = [
  [
    { label: "" }, // placeholder for Name
    { label: "Details", colSpan: 3 }
  ],
  [
    { label: "" }, // placeholder for Name
    { label: "" }, // placeholder for Age
    { label: "Address", colSpan: 2  }
  ],
  [
    { label: "Name", key: "name" },
    { label: "Age", key: "age" },
    { label: "City", key: "city" },
    { label: "Country", key: "country" },
  ]
]

I have tried to write the function, but nothing worked. The tricky party is adding the placeholders, so that every leaf column appears at the bottom.
Not sure if the result I gave above is the best representation for this, but I want to render such table headers inside an HTML table, and I figured that format would be the easiest to utilise.
Here is my (non-working) attempt.
export function isContainerColumn(
  col: TableColumn,
): col is TableContainerColumn {
  return "columns" in col && Array.isArray(col.columns);
}

interface FlatColumn extends TableLeafColumn {
  colSpan: number;
}

export function flattenColumns(
  columns: TableColumn[],
): FlatColumn[][] {
  const levels: FlatColumn[][] = [];

  function flatten(
    cols: TableColumn<any>[],
    depth: number,
  ): number {
    levels[depth] ??= [];

    let totalSpan = 0;

    cols.forEach((col) => {
      if (isContainerColumn(col)) {
        const childSpan = flatten(col.columns, depth + 1);
        totalSpan += childSpan;

        levels[depth]!.push({
          ...col,
          colSpan: childSpan,
        });
      }
      else {
        levels[depth]!.push({
          ...col,
          colSpan: 1,
        });

        totalSpan += 1;
      }
    });

    return totalSpan;
  }

  flatten(columns, 0);
  return levels;
}


@Yogi I added my attempt, but it doesn't work

What if there are multiple "Details" items at the same level (siblings), and they have different depths of nesting below them, then what will be the desired output. Can you give a less trivial example?

You could get colSpan for nested items first and then get rows for each level with prefilling of values.
A more complex example b with
[
    {
        label: "abcdefg",
        columns: [
            { label: "a", key: "a" },
            {
                label: "bcdefg",
                columns: [
                    {
                        label: "bcd",
                        columns: [
                            {
                                label: "bc",
                                columns: [
                                    { label: "b", key: "b" },
                                    { label: "c", key: "c" }
                                ]
                            },
                            { label: "d", key: "d" }
                        ]
                    },
                    { label: "e", key: "e" },
                    {
                        label: "fg",
                        columns: [
                            { label: "f", key: "f" },
                            { label: "g", key: "g" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "hij",
        columns: [
            { label: "h", key: "h" },
            {
                label: "ij",
                columns: [
                    { label: "i", key: "i"}, 
                    { label: "j", key: "j"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

result:
| abcdefg                   | hij       |
|   | bcdefg                |   | ij    |
|   | bcd       |   | fg    |   |   |   |
|   | bc    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 



const
    convert = columns => {
        const
            sizes = new WeakMap,
            getSizes = (o, wm) => {
                const size = o.columns.reduce((cs, q) => cs + (!q.columns || getSizes(q, wm)), 0) || 1
                wm.set(o, size);
                return size;
            },
            temp = { columns },
            values = [],
            result = [],
            indices = [],
            iterate = (o, level = 0) => {
                result[level] ??= [];
                indices[level] ??= 0;

                while (indices[level] < values.length) {
                    result[level].push({ label: '' });
                    indices[level]++;
                }

                o.columns.forEach(q => {
                    if (q.columns) {
                        const colSpan = sizes.get(q);
                        result[level].push({ label: q.label, colSpan });
                        indices[level] += colSpan;
                        iterate(q, level + 1);
                    } else {
                        values.push(q);
                        result[level].push({ label: '' });
                        indices[level]++;
                    }
                });

            };

        getSizes(temp, sizes);
        iterate(temp);

        result.length--;
        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            while (indices[i] < sizes.get(temp)) {
                result[i].push({ label: '' });
                indices[i]++;
            }
        }

        result.push(values);
        return result;
    },
    a = [{ label: "Name", key: "name" }, { label: "Details", columns: [{ label: "Age", key: "age" }, { label: "Address", columns: [{ label: "City", key: "city" }, { label: "Country", key: "country" }] }] }],
    b = [{ label: "abcdefg", columns: [{ label: "a", key: "a" }, { label: "bcdefg", columns: [{ label: "bcd", columns: [{ label: "bc", columns: [{ label: "b", key: "b" }, { label: "c", key: "c" }] }, { label: "d", key: "d" }] }, { label: "e", key: "e" }, { label: "fg", columns: [{ label: "f", key: "f" }, { label: "g", key: "g" }] }] }] }, { label: "hij", columns: [{ label: "h", key: "h" }, { label: "ij", columns: [{ label: "i", key: "i" }, { label: "j", key: "j" }] }] }];

console.log(convert(a));
console.log(convert(b));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }



